# NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc

Tags: linux, jdbc

So far here are the things I've checked from the server:

- DB2 JDBC Driver - check
- DB2 License (db2jcc_license_cu.jar) included in class path - check
- DB2 db2java.zip included in class path - check
- DB2 db2jcc.jar included in class path - check

Here's the current class path:

```
CLASSPATH=/home/db2cae/sqllib/java/db2java.zip:/home/db2cae/sqllib/java/sqlj.zip:/home/db2cae/sqllib/function:/home/db2cae/sqllib/java/db2jcc_license_cu.jar:/home/db2cae/sqllib/tools/clpplus.jar:/home/db2cae/sqllib/tools/antlr-3.2.jar:/home/db2cae/sqllib/tools/jline-0.9.93.jar:/home/db2cae/sqllib/java/db2jcc.jar:.
JAVA_BINDIR=/usr/lib64/jvm/jre/bin
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib64/jvm/jre
JAVA_ROOT=/usr/lib64/jvm/jre
```

The command that was executed was:

```
java -cp ./db2jcc.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version
```

However it returned

[image: NoClassDefFoundError]

What could be the possible problem for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i assume your classpath environment is not considered.
You could try someting like:

Windows:
java -cp %CLASSPATH%;./db2jcc4.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version

Linux:
java -cp $CLASSPATH:./db2jcc4.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version

Comment: In my case the issue was simply that I was referring to db2jcc.jar, but my .jar file was actually called db2jcc4.jar.  So the error would likely occur in any situation where the target jar file can't be found.